# How to ignore negative values in array in C

Tags: c

Every time I compute the negative values are always counted. How to exclude negative numbers in an array so it wont get computed on finding the mean.

```
int getMean(int sum)
{
    int result;

    result = sum / 5;

    return result;
}
int main()
{
    int a[100] , sum = 0, mean, i;

    for (i = 1; i <=  5;  i++)
    {
        printf("[%d]Enter numbers: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

        if (a[i] < 0)
         {
             printf("Whole numbers only, Try again\n");
             i--;
         }
         if (a[i] > 0)
         {
             sum += a[i];
         }
    }
    mean = getMean(sum);

    printf("Mean is: %d", mean);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you find a negative loop restart the body of the loop `if (a[i] < 0) { printf(...); i--; continue; }` otherwise you will carry on to the following `if` and mess up `sum`

Comment: Instead of `if (a[i] > 0)` use `else`. (Otherwise you process the value with the preceding index which may even be uninitialized if the first number is negative.) Note that in C an array index starts with 0, not 1. So your array `int a[100]` has an index range 0..99.

Comment: BTW: Using `scanf` for user input is problematic. You don't know if the user will enter something that matches your programs's format specification. You will get unexpected behavior if you enter something that cannot be converted to an integer number, e.g. `a` or `1.0`. I suggest to use `fgets` to read the whole line of input, process it with `sscanf` or `strtol` and check all return codes.

Comment: `"Whole numbers only, Try again\n"` does not match code `a[i] < 0`.  Is the goal to reject negative numbers or non-whole numbers?  Post sample input, output seen, output expected.

Comment: @Bodo thank you for the tip, ill try to use it next time. I hope our teacher will teach us how to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (a[i] < 0)
{
    printf("Whole numbers only, Try again\n");
    i--;
    continue;
}
```

I just added continue; at the end and it already did the job.

Comment: If this solved your issue check your answer as solution.

Comment: I already checked my answer and it skips the negative values and it excludes it in the inside of an array @CEPB

Comment: Accept your ANSWER. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png